# org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver click fail

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver

This is a help request!

In java's org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver, using webDriver.switchTo().frame("dad937da-760e-40b4-8143-5576c0ab6d0e").findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div")).click(); I have been unable to click the dropdown button. Could you please advise on how to locate it? I've tried classname and xpath, but neither can locate it. Please help with the locating method.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbazg.png)

I've tried classname and xpath, but neither can locate it. Please help with the locating method.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.